# Find CSS path in one page checkout extension in magento?

Tags: css, magento

I am using one page checkout extension,and my firebug is displaying this path..

checkout/onepage/#2.css

but i am unable to find this page,can anyone help me..

Comment: Check the css folders at the <ur magento folder>/skin/frontend/base/default.  I hope here you can see your extension folder. Try to search in those files

Comment: let me know once you got solved with this and how you fixed this issue.

Comment: actually the problem was based on magento cache and css was not putted in default extension folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the view source of your magento checkout page to find the one page checkout css path and file name accordingly.

Or

Check the page.xml file in your current store theme folder to findout the path.

Or

Check your onepage checkout Extension layout file in your current theme to know the path.

Comment: Always Welcome @mon. Glad to help you. Please accept my answer if really helps you.

Comment: i think you may get the jquery conflicts with magento prototype. So please put any new js files top of the prototype.js file